# 'Program log: AnchorError caused by account: refund_receiver. Error Code: ConstraintMut. Error Number: 2000. Error: A mut constraint was violated.'

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-client, anchor-test

lib.rs code

```
pub fn bid(ctx: Context<Bid>, price: u64) -> Result<()> {
    let auction = &mut ctx.accounts.auction;

    //
    // Check bidder's balance against auction's price.
    //
    if price < auction.price {
        return Err(error!(MarketError::InsufficientMoney));
    }

    if (Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp as u128) > auction.end_time {
        return Err(error!(MarketError::AuctionEnded));
    }

    //if refund_receiver exist return the money
    if auction.refund_receiver != Pubkey::default() {
        let seeds = &[
            b"auction",
            ctx.accounts.mint_key.key.as_ref(),
            &[auction.bump]
        ];
        let signer = &[&seeds[..]];
        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
        let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.auction_token_account.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.refund_receiver.to_account_info(),
            authority: auction.to_account_info()
        };
        let cpi_context = CpiContext::new_with_signer(cpi_program, cpi_accounts, signer);

        let result = transfer(cpi_context, auction.price);
        if let Err(_) = result {
            return Err(error!(MarketError::SolTransferFailed));
        }
    }

    // Transfer bid price to auction token account

    let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
        from: ctx.accounts.bidder_token_account.to_account_info(),
        to: ctx.accounts.auction_token_account.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.bidder.to_account_info()
    };
    let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
    let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
    let result = transfer(cpi_context, price);
    if let Err(_) = result {
        return Err(error!(MarketError::SolTransferFailed));
    }

    //update the auction info

    let auction = &mut ctx.accounts.auction;
    auction.refund_receiver = *ctx.accounts.bidder_token_account.to_account_info().key;
    auction.price = price;  

    Ok(())

  
}
```

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Bid<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [
            b"auction",
            mint_key.key.as_ref(),
        ],
        bump,
        has_one = creator,
        close = creator
    )]
    pub auction: Account<'info, Auction>,

    #[account(
        mut, 
        associated_token::mint = auction.mint_key,
        associated_token::authority = auction,
    )]
    pub auction_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    /// CHECK: This account's address is only used.
    pub mint_key: AccountInfo<'info>,

    /// CHECK: This account's address is only used.
    #[account(mut)]
    pub creator: AccountInfo<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub bidder: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        constraint=bidder_token_account.owner == bidder.key(),
        constraint=bidder_token_account.mint == mint_key.key(),
    )]
    pub bidder_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    /// CHECK: This account's address is only used.
    #[account(mut, "refund_receiver.key == &Pubkey::default() || refund_receiver.key == &auction.refund_receiver")]
    pub refund_receiver: AccountInfo<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
}
```

This is how I am calling in my test:

```
await program.methods
    .bid(new BN(price))
    .accounts({
      auction: auctionAccount,
      auctionTokenAccount: auctionTokenAccount,
      mintKey: mintKey,
      creator: ownerKey,
      bidder: bidder.key.publicKey,
      bidderTokenAccount: bidderTokenAccount,
      refundReceiver: auction.refundReceiver,
    })
    .rpc();
```

what am i doing wrong here??

```
failed: custom program error: 0x7d0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the error is but this error says that you are violating a constraint here:

```
/// CHECK: This account's address is only used.
    #[account(mut, "refund_receiver.key == &Pubkey::default() || refund_receiver.key == &auction.refund_receiver")]
    pub refund_receiver: AccountInfo<'info>,
```

afaik the standard way to specify constraints is as you did here:

```
    #[account(
        mut,
        constraint=bidder_token_account.owner == bidder.key(),
        constraint=bidder_token_account.mint == mint_key.key(),
    )]
    pub bidder_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
```

That syntax is a bit new to me.

basically try checking the places where you're providing the Pubkey of refund_receiver and auction.refund_receiver. Or add them to your problem so we can help!

Comment: I have added it... In bid function I use  auction.refund_receiver twice once in the if statement to compare it whether it is assigned a value..

Comment: Then at the end to assign it the publickey of bidder_token_account

Comment: Okay I defined constraints in the standard way but still gives same error. Can u plz check the "bid" Function provided at the top.

Comment: This is where I update the "auction.refund_receiver" in bid function

    let auction = &mut ctx.accounts.auction;
    auction.refund_receiver = *ctx.accounts.bidder_token_account.to_account_info().key;
    auction.price = price;  

    Ok(())

Comment: looking at your code i don't understand why do you pass refund_receiver separately? Isn't it already in the auction? Or is it to perform the checks?

Comment: To transfer refund amount. I need the account right. I can get the refund_receiver from auction but can I transfer refund amount to it without passing a "AccountInfo"  Context..?

Comment: I don't see why you can't, give it a try. When you make a transfer it is just a public key

Comment: Oh is it possible that way..? I thought we have to provide account in context.. I will give it a try and check

Comment: I cannot use auction.refund_receiver it gives error... Mismatch type.. I cannot use "to_account_info" On it either.. How to execute this transfer??

Comment: Should I use system_instruction::transfer and transfer from: auction.key() to: auction.refund_receiver.key()..?

Comment: did a bit of search :https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/1190/590

Comment: maybe keep the refund_receiver in the struct, but pass the pubkey instead of auction.receiver_key()

Comment: afaik system_instruction::transfer when transferring sol, not custom tokens

Comment: Sol transfer will do... I can transfer sol to "auction" account using system_instruction::transfer.. Right?

Comment: Transfer the bid amount in sol to auction account... Then I can refund from "auction" Account to the refund_receiver ryt... ? Using system:_instruction::transfer...?

Comment: if it is a sol account, then yes. Btw, if refund receiver is a pda, or for any transfers from pda to any other account, then it is a bit different:
https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/293/error-signature-verification-failed-when-using-pda-when-transfering-sol-from?rq=1

Comment: or this https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1158/how-to-withdraw-sol-from-a-pda/1304#1304

Comment: So in my above account.. Auction is defined as pda ryt?   So I could transfer sol to it using system_transfer and withdraw using 

**ctx.accounts.vault.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= amount;
**ctx.accounts.destination.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += amount;

Comment: in your case auction is a pda. yes

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the `signers` property when calling the instruction:

```
await program.methods
    .bid(new BN(price))
    .accounts({
      auction: auctionAccount,
      auctionTokenAccount: auctionTokenAccount,
      mintKey: mintKey,
      creator: ownerKey,
      bidder: bidder.key.publicKey,
      bidderTokenAccount: bidderTokenAccount,
      refundReceiver: auction.refundReceiver,
    })
    .signers([bidder.key])
    .rpc();
```

Comment: It still gives the same error